# How to send mail as another email address while hiding your official email address?

Tags: gmail

If I add a "Send mail as" email address to my Google account, I can send mail as another email address. This is useful, for example, if I want to send email from a colleague or a "support" type email address. When a user receives that email, they correctly see that it was sent from this new alias instead of my address in the UI at the top of the Gmail interface:

However, if the recipient chooses the "Show original" option, my real email address is revealed in several of the headers at top:

- ARC-Authentication-Results
- Return-Path
- Received-SPF
- Authentication-Results

Most of the time, it will show my email address in text such as:

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@example.com designates 1.1.1.1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@example.com;
```

Is there any way to send mail as another email address in Gmail without it revealing the original email address?